# Seekbar thumb should be appear as in picture below in android

Tags: android

I am writing code for BMI calculator and i want my seekbar should [look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mJrc.png). After spending a lot of time on solution i am here to ask if someone could help me out.
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, lets create a helper class for progress item to define progress span and color.
ProgressItem.java

```
public class ProgressItem {

    public int color;
    public float progressItemPercentage;
}
```

Now lets create a Custom seekbar class that extends SeekBar. We’ll use the list of progress items passed from our activity to show progress span and color for each progress item.
CustomSeekBar.java

```
    int progressBarWidth = getWidth();
    int progressBarHeight = getHeight();
    int thumboffset = getThumbOffset();
    int lastProgressX = 0;
    int progressItemWidth, progressItemRight;
    for (int i = 0; i < mProgressItemsList.size(); i++) {
        ProgressItem progressItem = mProgressItemsList.get(i);
        Paint progressPaint = new Paint();
        progressPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(progressItem.color));

        progressItemWidth = (int) (progressItem.progressItemPercentage
                * progressBarWidth / 100);

        progressItemRight = lastProgressX + progressItemWidth;

        // for last item give right of the progress item to width of the
        // progress bar
        if (i == mProgressItemsList.size() - 1
                && progressItemRight != progressBarWidth) {
            progressItemRight = progressBarWidth;
        }
        Rect progressRect = new Rect();
        progressRect.set(lastProgressX, thumboffset / 2, progressItemRight,
                progressBarHeight - thumboffset / 2);
        canvas.drawRect(progressRect, progressPaint);
        lastProgressX = progressItemRight;
    }
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

In onDraw method, we’ve calculated width of progress item with respect to the width of whole progressbar. Left position for the progress item will be right position of the previous item, for the first progress item, it will be 0. Use left position and width of progress item to get right position of the item. Now, draw a rectangle using these positions. Call super.onDraw(canvas) method right after add your custom changes.
Now, you can add your CustomSeekBar from your activity or xml file. I’ve added this it in xml file as
activity_main.xml

```
<yourpackagename.CustomSeekBar
        android:id="@+id/customSeekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="0"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/transparent"
        android:thumb="@drawable/seek_thumb_normal"
        android:thumbOffset="12dp" />
```

Since we’re not showing any progressDrawable so use transparent drawable here.
Add your progress items in your activity.
MainActivity.java

```
private CustomSeekBar seekbar;
private float totalSpan = 1500;
private float redSpan = 200;
private float blueSpan = 300;
private float greenSpan = 400;
private float yellowSpan = 150;
private float darkGreySpan;
    private ArrayList<ProgressItem> progressItemList;
private ProgressItem mProgressItem;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    seekbar = ((CustomSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.customSeekBar));
    initDataToSeekbar();
    }

    private void initDataToSeekbar() {
    progressItemList = new ArrayList<ProgressItem>();
    // red span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = ((redSpan / totalSpan) * 100);
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.red;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // blue span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (blueSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.blue;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // green span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (greenSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.green;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // yellow span
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (yellowSpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.yellow;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);
    // greyspan
    mProgressItem = new ProgressItem();
    mProgressItem.progressItemPercentage = (darkGreySpan / totalSpan) * 100;
    mProgressItem.color = R.color.grey;
    progressItemList.add(mProgressItem);

    seekbar.initData(progressItemList);
    seekbar.invalidate();
}
```

> All credit goes to
>   https://azzits.wordpress.com/2013/11/17/customseekbar/

Comment: thanks @anisuzzaman babla. i am implementing this solution and gonna accept your answer if it works. Appreciated.

Comment: Welcome bro. Best of luck.